# How to break <td> inbetween multiple <td>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the below html.

```html
 <tr>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="">Category</td>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap break" data-label=""><strong> Test </strong></td>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="">Format</td>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap break" data-label=""><strong>Test 1</strong></td>
</tr>
```

I want the output to be like below.

```
Category Format
Test     Test1
```

Note that the 2nd `<td>` and the 4th `<td>` are in a new line.

How do I achieve this using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:grid` is ideal for this.

```css
tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
}
td.break {
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="">Category</td>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap break" data-label=""><strong> Test </strong></td>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="">Format</td>
     <td class="slds-cell-wrap break" data-label=""><strong>Test 1</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use CSS for this table all you need is HTML. For the table headers, you have to put a `<th>` tag inside a `<tr>` tag  so it goes something like this:

```html
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="">Category</th>
    <th class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="">Format</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td class="slds-cell-wrap break" data-label=""><strong> Test </strong></td>
    <td class="slds-cell-wrap break" data-label=""><strong>Test 1</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The issue is that only for mobile view, I face this issue. So if I add those headers now, it will affect the desktop view. What’s the best way to go about?

Comment: For the desktop view, I don’t want it to be in the next line.

Comment: So you want this solution only for mobile view?

Comment: Yes, that’s the reason I wanted to make this change in css. I’m not sure how to bring the 2nd and 4th td to next line